# Auto-complete from master document in Kile

Tags: kile, auto-completion

I am working in Kile with a latex project composed of several files.
I use ``Define current document as Master document'' to enable compiling the main file, even when I am browsing a different file.
Defining a master document also enables inverse and forward search well.
However, I do not get the macro auto-completion I like so much.

That is, 
suppose in main.tex I have a definition
\newcommand{\sub}[1]{A_{#1}}

When I start typing \su in the main.tex I will get the suggestion
\sub{x}
but if do the same in another document,
I don't get the suggested auto-complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty simple. You just need to start a project -

and add all files to the project[image]